# OpenXml bullet list properties for word

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

i'm generaing bullet list using OpenXML for word doc, its working good but i need to set indent between margin and  bullet character,bullet character and paragraph

```
NumberingProperties _bulletsNumberingProp = new NumberingProperties();
                NumberingLevelReference _bulletNumberingLevelRef = new NumberingLevelReference();
                _bulletNumberingLevelRef.Val = _level; // level comes here 

                NumberingId _bulletNumberingId = new NumberingId();
                //if (_level != 3)
                //{
                //iParentID = TemplateElementID;
                //_bulletNumberingId.Val = iParentID;
                _bulletNumberingId.Val = TemplateElementID;
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    _bulletNumberingId.Val = _pId;
                //    iParentID = _pId;
                //}
                _bulletsNumberingProp.Append(_bulletNumberingLevelRef);
                _bulletsNumberingProp.Append(_bulletNumberingId);




                GenerateNumberingDefinitionPart(numberingPart, ctcObj, _pId, _level, numbering, TemplateElementID, iParentID);
```

Here the method to generate numbering list

```
private void GenerateNumberingDefinitionPart(NumberingDefinitionsPart numberingPart, CAPSTemplateClass ctcObj, int _pId, int _level, Numbering numbering, int tempElementId, int iParentID)
    {
        //iParentID = _pId;
        iParentID = tempElementId;
        string charUniCode = Convert.ToString(ctcObj.BulletData.BulletCharacterUnicode);
        NumberingFormat _numberingFormat = new NumberingFormat();
        switch (charUniCode)
        {
            case "49":
                _numberingFormat.Val = NumberFormatValues.Decimal;
                break;
            case "65":
                _numberingFormat.Val = NumberFormatValues.UpperLetter;
                break;
            case "97":
                _numberingFormat.Val = NumberFormatValues.LowerLetter;
                break;
            case "73":
                _numberingFormat.Val = NumberFormatValues.UpperRoman;
                break;
            case "105":
                _numberingFormat.Val = NumberFormatValues.LowerRoman;
                break;

        }

        AbstractNum abstractNum1 = new AbstractNum() { AbstractNumberId = iParentID }; //tempElementId 
        MultiLevelType multiLevelType1 = new MultiLevelType() { Val = MultiLevelValues.HybridMultilevel };
        TemplateCode templateCode1 = new TemplateCode() { Val = "BCF81B36" };

        Level level0 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 0 };
        StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue0 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
        NumberingFormat numberingFormat0 = new NumberingFormat();
        numberingFormat0.Val = _numberingFormat.Val;
        LevelText levelText0 = new LevelText() { Val = (ctcObj.BulletData.PrefixText + "%1" + ctcObj.BulletData.PostfixText) };
        LevelJustification levelJustification0 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

        PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties0 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();
        Indentation indentation0 = new Indentation() { Start = "720", Hanging = "360" };

        previousParagraphProperties0.Append(indentation0);
        //Level lvl = SetNumBulletsLevel(_level, ctcObj);
        //abstractNum1.Append();
        level0.Append(startNumberingValue0);
        level0.Append(numberingFormat0);
        level0.Append(levelText0);
        level0.Append(levelJustification0);
        level0.Append(previousParagraphProperties0);

        Level level1 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 1, TemplateCode = "04090019", Tentative = true };
        StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue1 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
        NumberingFormat numberingFormat1 = new NumberingFormat();
        numberingFormat1.Val = _numberingFormat.Val;
        LevelText levelText1 = new LevelText() { Val = (ctcObj.BulletData.PrefixText + "%2" + ctcObj.BulletData.PostfixText) };
        LevelJustification levelJustification1 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

        //lvlrst.Append(
        //level1.LevelRestart = level0;
        PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties1 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();
        Indentation indentation1 = new Indentation() { Start = "1440", Hanging = "360" };

        previousParagraphProperties1.Append(indentation1);

        level1.Append(startNumberingValue1);
        level1.Append(numberingFormat1);
        level1.Append(levelText1);
        level1.Append(levelJustification1);
        level1.Append(previousParagraphProperties1);
        //level1.Append(indentation1);
        //LevelRestart lvlrestart = new LevelRestart();
        //lvlrestart.Append(level0);
        //level1.LevelRestart = lvlrestart;
        Level level2 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 2, TemplateCode = "0409001B", Tentative = true };
        StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue2 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
        NumberingFormat numberingFormat2 = new NumberingFormat();
        numberingFormat2.Val = _numberingFormat.Val;
        LevelText levelText2 = new LevelText() { Val = (ctcObj.BulletData.PrefixText + "%3" + ctcObj.BulletData.PostfixText) };
        LevelJustification levelJustification2 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Right };

        PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties2 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();
        Indentation indentation2 = new Indentation() { Start = "2160", Hanging = "360" };

        previousParagraphProperties2.Append(indentation2);

        level2.Append(startNumberingValue2);
        level2.Append(numberingFormat2);
        level2.Append(levelText2);
        level2.Append(levelJustification2);
        level2.Append(previousParagraphProperties2);
        //level2.Append(indentation2);

        Level level3 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 3, TemplateCode = "0409000F", Tentative = true };
        StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue3 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
        NumberingFormat numberingFormat3 = new NumberingFormat();
        numberingFormat3.Val = _numberingFormat.Val;
        LevelText levelText3 = new LevelText() { Val = (ctcObj.BulletData.PrefixText + "%4" + ctcObj.BulletData.PostfixText) };
        LevelJustification levelJustification3 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

        PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties3 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();
        Indentation indentation3 = new Indentation() { Start = "2880", Hanging = "360" };

        previousParagraphProperties3.Append(indentation3);

        level3.Append(startNumberingValue3);
        level3.Append(numberingFormat3);
        level3.Append(levelText3);
        level3.Append(levelJustification3);
        level3.Append(previousParagraphProperties3);
        //level3.Append(indentation3);

        Level level4 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 4, TemplateCode = "04090019", Tentative = true };
        StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue4 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
        NumberingFormat numberingFormat4 = new NumberingFormat();
        numberingFormat4.Val = _numberingFormat.Val;
        LevelText levelText4 = new LevelText() { Val = (ctcObj.BulletData.PrefixText + "%5" + ctcObj.BulletData.PostfixText) };
        LevelJustification levelJustification4 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

        PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties4 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();
        Indentation indentation4 = new Indentation() { Start = "3600", Hanging = "360" };

        previousParagraphProperties4.Append(indentation4);

        level4.Append(startNumberingValue4);
        level4.Append(numberingFormat4);
        level4.Append(levelText4);
        level4.Append(levelJustification4);
        level4.Append(previousParagraphProperties4);


        Level level5 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 5, TemplateCode = "0409001B", Tentative = true };
        StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue5 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
        NumberingFormat numberingFormat5 = new NumberingFormat();
        numberingFormat5.Val = _numberingFormat.Val;
        LevelText levelText5 = new LevelText() { Val = (ctcObj.BulletData.PrefixText + "%6" + ctcObj.BulletData.PostfixText) };
        LevelJustification levelJustification5 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Right };

        PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties5 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();
        Indentation indentation5 = new Indentation() { Start = "4320", Hanging = "180" };

        previousParagraphProperties5.Append(indentation5);

        level5.Append(startNumberingValue5);
        level5.Append(numberingFormat5);
        level5.Append(levelText5);
        level5.Append(levelJustification5);
        level5.Append(previousParagraphProperties5);

        Level level6 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 6, TemplateCode = "0409000F", Tentative = true };
        StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue6 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
        NumberingFormat numberingFormat6 = new NumberingFormat();
        numberingFormat6.Val = _numberingFormat.Val;
        LevelText levelText6 = new LevelText() { Val = (ctcObj.BulletData.PrefixText + "%7" + ctcObj.BulletData.PostfixText) };
        LevelJustification levelJustification6 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

        PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties6 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();
        Indentation indentation6 = new Indentation() { Start = "5040", Hanging = "360" };

        previousParagraphProperties6.Append(indentation6);

        level6.Append(startNumberingValue6);
        level6.Append(numberingFormat6);
        level6.Append(levelText6);
        level6.Append(levelJustification6);
        level6.Append(previousParagraphProperties6);

        Level level7 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 7, TemplateCode = "04090019", Tentative = true };
        StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue7 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
        NumberingFormat numberingFormat7 = new NumberingFormat();
        numberingFormat7.Val = _numberingFormat.Val;
        LevelText levelText7 = new LevelText() { Val = (ctcObj.BulletData.PrefixText + "%8" + ctcObj.BulletData.PostfixText) };
        LevelJustification levelJustification7 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Left };

        PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties7 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();
        Indentation indentation7 = new Indentation() { Start = "5760", Hanging = "360" };

        previousParagraphProperties7.Append(indentation7);

        level7.Append(startNumberingValue7);
        level7.Append(numberingFormat7);
        level7.Append(levelText7);
        level7.Append(levelJustification7);
        level7.Append(previousParagraphProperties7);

        Level level8 = new Level() { LevelIndex = 8, TemplateCode = "0409001B", Tentative = true };
        StartNumberingValue startNumberingValue8 = new StartNumberingValue() { Val = 1 };
        NumberingFormat numberingFormat8 = new NumberingFormat();
        numberingFormat8.Val = _numberingFormat.Val;
        LevelText levelText8 = new LevelText() { Val = (ctcObj.BulletData.PrefixText + "%9" + ctcObj.BulletData.PostfixText) };
        LevelJustification levelJustification8 = new LevelJustification() { Val = LevelJustificationValues.Right };

        PreviousParagraphProperties previousParagraphProperties8 = new PreviousParagraphProperties();
        Indentation indentation8 = new Indentation() { Start = "6480", Hanging = "180" };

        previousParagraphProperties8.Append(indentation8);

        level8.Append(startNumberingValue8);
        level8.Append(numberingFormat8);
        level8.Append(levelText8);
        level8.Append(levelJustification8);
        level8.Append(previousParagraphProperties8);

        abstractNum1.Append(multiLevelType1);
        abstractNum1.Append(templateCode1);
        abstractNum1.Append(level0);
        abstractNum1.Append(level1);
        abstractNum1.Append(level2);
        abstractNum1.Append(level3);
        abstractNum1.Append(level4);
        abstractNum1.Append(level5);
        abstractNum1.Append(level6);
        abstractNum1.Append(level7);
        abstractNum1.Append(level8);

        //tempElementId = numbId;

        NumberingInstance numberingInstance1 = new NumberingInstance() { NumberID = iParentID }; //tempElementId
        AbstractNumId abstractNumId1 = new AbstractNumId() { Val = iParentID };
        //numbId = numbId + 1;

        numberingInstance1.Append(abstractNumId1);

        numbering.Append(abstractNum1);


        numInstance.Add(numberingInstance1);
    }
```

> im getting result like below by default
>
> 1. Bullet1
>
> but i need to set indent before and after number value like below
>   Blockquote
>           1.   Bullet1

Answer (score 3):

Try to create the desired structure in word manually and open it in OpenXML Productivity tool to get the code.

You can get open xml productivity tool along with Open XML SDK from here https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5

Hope this helps.